# How to say "Best Dad" in Italian?

Tags: translation, phrase-request

In English, one might say "Best Dad" or "Number one Dad". What is the Italian equivalence (or better yet, a saying) of this meaning?

Something that can be stated regarding a father other than one's own father.

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE, @Pamela!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd  say:

> - Il migliore dei papà.

or,

> - Il numero uno dei papà.

Comment: Thanks, I like "Il migliore dei papà"; however, do you know of any shorter way of writing/saying the same thing?

Comment: Not that I think of, but the two English expressions would be easily understood in Italy I guess.

Comment: Written, would "#1 Papà" also be correct?

Comment: No, sounds like ; one dad.

Comment: @Pamela The Italian equivalent on "#1 dad" is "Papà n. 1" or "Babbo n° 1".

Answer (score 3):

These ones sound slightly more idiomatic to me: *il papà migliore del mondo*, *il papà più bravo del mondo*. But I must say that this expression is not common in Italian.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest "Un padre ideale" (Il Tempo.it 9.3.2013: «Il padre ideale? Vero e sincero con i suoi difetti») (and: Biblioteca digitale di psicanalisi - Il Padre Ideale). If he is ideal, he must be the best.